# tooltip on hover has different position in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, tooltip

I tried to make a tooltip with pseudo elements on hover on button. but it works in google chrome and not in safari. I added webkit as well but nothing changed.

here's my code, I used transform property, I tried top bottom left and right but still nothing.

```
 <div class="buttonhover">
 <button class="button" data-button="order your copy now">ORDER YOUR COPY NOW</button>
  </div>

.buttonhover {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-left: 5em;
}
.button{
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   background-color: coral;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 0.3em;
}
.button::before,
.button::after {
    
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
.button::before {
    content: "";
    border-width: 0 8px 10px 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) transparent;
    transform: translate(450%, 330%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(450%, 330%);
}
.button::after {
    content: attr(data-button);
    width: 10em;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 0.5em 0.7em;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    transform: translate(-105%, 150%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-105%, 150%);
    top: 0.4em;
}
.button:hover::before,
.button:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: There are a fair few user-agent-specific styles on `<button>` elements, especially Safari. Might work more reliably cross-browser with a css reset or at least a neutral element like `<div>` with `display: inline-block` etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using length units that are relative to a font-size, you want to make sure all browsers use the same font-size (and possibly font-family).